# Linux awk text file processing

Tags: linux, awk, text-processing

I have a file with a few thousand lines of data, each line is like: `a:b:c:d`

So for example:

```
0.0:2000.00:2000.04:2000.02
```

I want to get all a's in one file, b's in second file etc. How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way. Output files will be named **fileX**, with **X** for each column number.

Assuming **infile** with content:

```
0.0:2000.00:2000.04:2001.02
0.1:2002.00:2000.05:2003.02
0.2:2003.00:2002.04:2004.02
0.3:2001.00:2000.05:2000.03
0.3:2001.00:2000.04:2001.02
0.2:2001.00:2002.04:2000.02
```

Execute this `awk` command:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = ":";
    }

    {
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
            print $i > "file" i;
        }
    }
' infile
```

Check output files:

```
head file[1234]
```

With following result:

```
==> file1 <==
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.3
0.2

==> file2 <==
2000.00
2002.00
2003.00
2001.00
2001.00
2001.00

==> file3 <==
2000.04
2000.05
2002.04
2000.05
2000.04
2002.04

==> file4 <==
2001.02
2003.02
2004.02
2000.03
2001.02
2000.02
```

Comment: Nice, but 11 lines of script for a one-liner is a bit excessive.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) (or [`gawk`](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.html)) manual.

You should use the `-F:` flag to set the field separator to `:`.

You should use `print` with `> file` to get the outputs to the file you want.

```
awk -F: '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { file = "file." i; print $i > file; } }' input
```

(`awk` on Mac OS X 10.7.4 does not permit an expression as the file name; `gawk` does.  The solution shown will work on both.)

Comment: @tripleee: `cut` does not do the I/O redirection in a single pass over the data.  For small files, rescanning doesn't matter.  For pipelines (no file) or large files, it might (though there are ways around 'no file' in a pipeline, of course).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
cat filename|cut -d ':' -f1 > a.txt
```

Then you can write -f2 for the second field and put it in b.txt.

Comment: You can do this (use `cut` 4 times); it involves 4 passes over the file for 4 fields, which doesn't matter much if the file exists and is small, but becomes a nuisance if there isn't a file (it is a result generated in a pipeline, for example), or if the file is large (for a suitable definition of large, which is probably measured in multiples of megabyte).  You also win a [UUOC](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) award.

Comment: Yeah, I see! Of course if it isn't a file, but something like a stream of data, you can't use this. But it's not the question. For very large file you're right, it's a waste of time.
Ps: really a funny award!